# R - readLines outputs empty lines

Tags: r, file, readlines

I have encountered some strange behaviour of the `readLines()`-function which is basically included for all R-runs. As I have done it houndreds or thousands of times before, I tried to read the lines of a file like this:

```
workingDir <- ""

tempFile <- file(paste(workingDir, "/stationaer_mittel004_head3D.csv", sep="", collapse=""), open="r")
s_mittel001_head <- readLines(tempFile)
close(tempFile)
s_mittel001_head
```

This does not read the file content properly and results in something like this:

```
[1] "\"" ""   ""   ""   ""
```

I have double- and tripöle and quadruple-checked if I have done something wrong with the filename but it works just fine when accessing the file in a file- or webbrowser. Subsequently, I plainly copied the file content to another csv and tried to open this one. It actually worked. I am on the administrive account of my laptop and both files show no special permission restrictions. Creating a new file with the same filename solves the issue, too.

**That's why I would like to know if somebody knows what might cause this behaviour.

Thank you!**

Comment: You can call readLines directly on the file name, you don't need to open and close a connection.

Comment: Looks like the usual  <CR> vs <LF> vs <CR><LF> line termination problem.  Your original file may have been created with some Satan's Spawn like MicrosoftWord, and thus has undesirable EOL characters.

Comment: Actually, it was created by Modelmuse, a pre- and postprocessor for the groundwater flow model Modflow (and friends). After creating similiar files using the same functionalities, I definately agree with you. It is just the way Modelmuse outputs the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CarlWitthoft pointed out, `readLines()` has problems reading ASCII-files with certain linebreak-types (don't know which exactly:  vs  vs ). This results in a list of practically empty strings. Furthermore, the function seemingly is unable to see the end of the file.

The final solution: Copy and paste the file content in a new file using a program with "more appropiate" linebreak-standard.

Answer (score 0):

For me this lead me to this post https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/857 where the comment by **mcleanle** set me down the right path.
The root cause was actually the encoding language.  My file was encoded as `UCS-2 LE BOM`, changing to `UTF-8` fixed this for me.